# Custom Control with Standard Child Controls - Why are their IDs null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I want to create a custom control ideally like this:

```
<foo:Frobnicate runat="server">
    <DoStuffWithThese>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fizzbot" />
    </DoStuffWithThese>
    <!-- other controls can be in the wrapper but outside the DoSomeStuffWithThese collection -->       
    <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="othercontrol" />
</foo:Frobnicate>
```

although I would settle for this if necessary:

```
<foo:Frobnicate runat="server">
    <DoStuffWithThese>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="fizzbot" />
    </DoStuffWithThese>
    <AndOtherStuffWithThese>      
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="othercontrol" />
    </AndOtherStuffWithThese>
</foo:Frobnicate>
```

I can access the controls in the codebehind OK (in the second, not-ideal example), but **for some reason their IDs (which I need) are NULL**.

Here is the codebehind:

```
[ParseChildren(true)]
public class Frobnicate : WebControl {

       [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
       public List<WebControl> DoStuffWithThese { get; set; }

       [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
       public List<WebControl> AndOtherStuffWithThese { get; set; }

       public override OnLoad(EventArgs e) {
         base.OnLoad(e);

         foreach(Control currentControl in DoStuffWithThese) {
           // the control can be accessed (e.g. I can see it's a TextBox, etc.
           // but currentControl.ID == null here -- why? :(
         }

}
```

Does anyone know why this is? And more importantly, how I can fix it so I can get a custom control in one of those formats and able to access the IDs?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to implement `INamingContainer` in your class, WebControl doesn't do that on its own. Note that it's just a marker interface, you don't need any code. Also, instead of a list of controls, you should probably use `ITemplate` (which allows you to actually create the controls and use them in the output of your control).

This should be helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6(v=vs.85).aspx

If this isn't what you want, please elaborate on what you're actually trying to do, and why you don't want to use templates.

To explain a bit more - just by adding a reference to a server control, you're not actually adding it anywhere to the page / control tree, which means it isn't *actually* created, and it doesn't work as part of the page, really (which includes a useful UniqueID/ClientID, and pretty much any logic except for the constructor).

When you have the template, you can use data binding to fill in the required data etc., and you can access the controls using `FindControl`, for example (or just use the `Controls` collection, but be aware that the template will likely also contain literals and other stuff than just your controls).

Answer (score 0):

Can you get the id of the dropdown? If so, I think it has to do with the other items missing runat=server.

Comment: No I can get neither the dropdown or the textbox ID = whatever is in the custom control, I can access it, but OnLoad of the custom control, the ID is null. Will update code example to include runat server in the container

Comment: Hi Whisker: the code works on my end. Not sure why. I did have to make some changes to get this working. Only the second example works.